# How to get javascript slider to work!

Tags: theme-development, css, javascript

I've only just started to develop my own themes and i'm stuck adding javascript to my slider.

I've added the slider into my index.php file as below:

```
<div class="carousel">


    <div class="carousel__content">
        <div class="item">
    <p class="title">First</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/70AD96/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
  </div>
        <div class="item">
    <p class="title">Second</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/EA4E23/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
  </div>
        <div class="item">
    <p class="title">Third</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/9BA452/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
  </div>
        <div class="item">
    <p class="title">Fourth</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/472D38/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
  </div>
        <div class="item">
    <p class="title">Fifth</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/F77C85/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
  </div>
        <div class="item">
    <p class="title">Sixth</p>
    <p class="title title--sub">Last Item</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x850/00FFAE/FFF&text=&nbsp;" alt="">
  </div>
    </div>

<div class="carousel__nav">
  <a href="#" class="nav nav--left">Previous</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav nav--right">Next</a>
</div>
```

And then created a js/slider-js.js file with the following:

```
( function () {
var carouselContent, carouselIndex, carouselLength, firstClone, firstItem, isAnimating, itemWidth, lastClone, lastItem;
carouselContent = $('.carousel__content');
carouselIndex = 0;
carouselLength = carouselContent.children().length;
isAnimating = false;
itemWidth = 100 / carouselLength;
firstItem = $(carouselContent.children()[0]);
lastItem = $(carouselContent.children()[carouselLength - 1]);
firstClone = null;
lastClone = null;
carouselContent.css('width', carouselLength * 100 + '%');
carouselContent.transition({ x: carouselIndex * -itemWidth + '%' }, 0);
$.each(carouselContent.children(), function () {
    return $(this).css('width', itemWidth + '%');
});
$('.nav--left').on('click', function () {
    if (isAnimating) {
        return;
    }
    isAnimating = true;
    carouselIndex--;
    if (carouselIndex === -1) {
        lastItem.prependTo(carouselContent);
        carouselContent.transition({ x: (carouselIndex + 2) * -itemWidth + '%' }, 0);
        return carouselContent.transition({ x: (carouselIndex + 1) * -itemWidth + '%' }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
            carouselIndex = carouselLength - 1;
            lastItem.appendTo(carouselContent);
            carouselContent.transition({ x: carouselIndex * -itemWidth + '%' }, 0);
            return isAnimating = false;
        });
    } else {
        return carouselContent.transition({ x: carouselIndex * -itemWidth + '%' }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
            return isAnimating = false;
        });
    }
});
$('.nav--right').on('click', function () {
    if (isAnimating) {
        return;
    }
    isAnimating = true;
    carouselIndex++;
    return carouselContent.transition({ x: carouselIndex * -itemWidth + '%' }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
        isAnimating = false;
        if (firstClone) {
            carouselIndex = 0;
            carouselContent.transition({ x: carouselIndex * -itemWidth + '%' }, 0);
            firstClone.remove();
            firstClone = null;
            carouselLength = carouselContent.children().length;
            itemWidth = 100 / carouselLength;
            carouselContent.css('width', carouselLength * 100 + '%');
            $.each(carouselContent.children(), function () {
                return $(this).css('width', itemWidth + '%');
            });
            return;
        }
        if (carouselIndex === carouselLength - 1) {
            carouselLength++;
            itemWidth = 100 / carouselLength;
            firstClone = firstItem.clone();
            firstClone.addClass('clone');
            firstClone.appendTo(carouselContent);
            carouselContent.css('width', carouselLength * 100 + '%');
            $.each(carouselContent.children(), function () {
                return $(this).css('width', itemWidth + '%');
            });
            return carouselContent.transition({ x: carouselIndex * -itemWidth + '%' }, 0);
        }
    });
});
```

}.call(this));

and then linked it to my functions.php with the following:

```
function skinsave_2016_slider() {
wp_enqueue_script('skinsave_2016-slider-js', content_url('/js/slider-js.js'), array(), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'skinsave_2016_slider');
```

I also added the following between the  tags in my header.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('skinsave_2016'); ?>/js/slider-js.js"></script>
```

And the css:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  font-family: "europa-1","europa-2", sans-serif;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/**
 * Use this wrapper only for demo purposes
 * So you can show the items outside the wrapper
 */
}
.wrapper--demo:before {
  left: -800px;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel .carousel__content {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel .carousel__content .item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel .carousel__content .item .title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin: -33px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
  color: #FFF;
}
.carousel .carousel__content .item .title--sub {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  opacity: .5;
}
.carousel .carousel__content .item img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .8rem;
  transition: padding .25s ease;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav .nav:hover {
  padding: 8px 20px;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav .nav--left {
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
}
.carousel .carousel__nav .nav--right {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
}
```

The slider loads fine but doesn't display as a slider, rather a list of blocks. I have a feeling it's the implementation of the javascript that's the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your carousel is highly customized, could you add the css too so it's clearer on what you're trying to do?  And it seems that you are not executing this function at all, it should end in () so you can execute in place, like this -> (function() {})();

Comment: Hi, i'm pasting this above

Comment: What errors do you see in the inspector console? Is the js loading correctly?

Comment: Also wp_enqueue_script should be called in the wp_enqueue_scripts hook, not wp_head.

Comment: I get Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Only changed the enqueue to script as i read in a tutorial that this made it work somehow!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the enqueueing part to this:

```
function skinsave_2016_slider() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skinsave_2016-slider-js', get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/js/slider-js.js', array(), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'skinsave_2016_slider');
```

The problem was your function `content_url()` returns `http://yourdomain.com/wp-content`, and not the URL of the template. `get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )` does return `http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/yourthemeslug`.

The second version you tried you wrote `bloginfo('skinsave_2016');`, where 'skinsave_2016' is not a valid argument.

Stick with the first version though, because it is the right way.

Also be sure your theme calls `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`!